# Java Connection refused in Client server application

Tags: java

I am building a Client server app in java ,here is my code

**Client**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class ClientCode{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        int character;
        Socket socket = new Socket("112.134.214.53", 8765);
 //i have put my public ip instead of 127.0.0.1 in order to test it is working through the internet or not
        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
        String string = "Hello!\n";
        byte buffer[] = string.getBytes();
        out.write(buffer);
        while ((character = in.read()) != -1){
            System.out.print((char) character);
        }
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

**Server**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class ServerCode{
    public static void main(String[] args ){
        try{
            ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(8765);
            Socket insocket = socket.accept( );
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(insocket.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(insocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            String instring = in.readLine();
            out.println("The server got this: " + instring);
            insocket.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

both are running on a same machine connected to internet using my home adsl single port router.

Server application run fine but when my client connects to the server through public ip the problem starts ,below is the error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at ClientCode.main(ClientCode.java:6)
```

My Kaspersky Network monitor is showing me that my port 8765 is ok and working

Comment: Are you missing part of the exception? It looks like it's cut off.

Comment: @Shakedown No this is what i got from eclipse IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be two possible reasons for this exception to occur:

1-  There is no service listening to the port you are attempting to connect to. For debugging you can try loading [http://112.134.214.53:8765](http://112.134.214.53:8765/) using a browser and see if it connects with the server.

2- (If everything else is fine) This could very well be a firewall issue.

Comment: Thanks but i stopped both window 7 and kaspersky firewalls, At the same time if i give the local ip it works fine , but not with the public ip; will it work with http ; will it work with http ; when i type 112.134.214.53 i can able to connect to my router configuration screen which means my public IP is correct.

Comment: @vibeeshanRC: this thread seems relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602167/java-networking-connection-refused-yes-my-server-is-running.

Comment: the accepted answer states: "Some routers doesn't allow the internal network to connect to the external IP address of the router.

You can try to use telnet to connect to your server socket. If telnet isn't able to establish a connection, it's likely a networking problem."

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem too. I was using Netbeans and I kept getting "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused:" But then I tried using jGrasp and it worked... Maybe this can provide some extra troubleshooting help. Also it could be that you just need a Java policy file.