# Java Socket connection refused with my Public IP

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking

I have a client server architecture project in android. I cant connect with my public IP to server. I closed firewall, and did the port redirection for server. My friend can connect from outside to my server, but i can't, why? how can it be?..
Thanks..

Comment: I dont understand the exact meaning the behind router; but yes i guess. I have a internal network. But i want to connect to server by my public ip which concludes with refuse.

Comment: This type of error happens if
1 ) you have a bad host name or port 
2 ) Server is not listening
3 ) You are block by firewall (router has firewall, you have to make port-forwarding )

Comment: all 3 steps is done.. i told My friend to connect from his home.He can connect from outside.. But i cant connect to my own server, interestingly.. I also check from wireshark. Packets are coming but it has bad cheksums.. It is refused

Comment: Some routers doesn't allow the internal network to connect to the external IP address of the router. Try telnet or SSH access. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602167/java-networking-connection-refused-yes-my-server-is-running)

Answer (score 1):

Which OS are you running your client server code. If Windows, look for c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts, if it's linux go the /etc/hosts/ file

Open the file with sudo privileges.

```
Format:
<IP> <HOSTNAME>.<DOMAIN> <ALIAS>

Example:
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
```

Add your IP here with domain name. Your Domain Name can be anything and try again. Also your question is a bit vague. Please add more details such as your os env and what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: OS : Windows.. Its a simple socket connection..
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(12345);

client --> InetSocketAddr addr : "my public ip",12345..

connection is refused it sayss.